# Carousel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I wanted to add a basic sliding carousel to my website and after a lot of seraching found [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/). I followed everything as per instructions but no matter what i do, it doesnt work. Below is the full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Carousel</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl/owl.carousel.js"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl/owl.theme.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl/owl.animate.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
       <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
       <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
        }
        }));
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** The output to the browser is just a series of numbers  displayed vertically rather than a horizontal carousel.

I am sure the required CSS and Javascript files are all in place. Please resolve this problem someone.

Comment: Step 1: Check your browser console for errors. And if that doesn't help, then show us a live example.

Comment: Missing `{` after `owlCaraousel(`, at the very least check your browser debugger for errors.

Comment: @DavidNguyen I apologize. There are no errors per say.I get an undesired output. Adding the '{' doesn't make any difference though.'  I have edited the question to include the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing one `}` more that you open. Try changing this:

```
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
        }
        }));
    });
    </script>
```

To this:

```
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
        }));
    });
    </script>
```

Or add in the `function({...});`
Hope it helps!